# Sending JSON to server

Tags: javascript, python, json, http, tornado

I am trying to send a json to my server via ajax request. It's about an web app intagrated in jupyter lab and I want to save a file in cloud instead of saving it locally, thus I need to send the json to server and then save it as a json file.

I tried an ajax POST request on client-side.

```
          $.ajax({  
          url: '/discoverjson',
          data: jsonString,
          contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        });
```

And I am requesting a response in tornado web server like this:

```
class JSONHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("/discoverjson"):
            self.json_args = json.loads(self.request.body)
            self.write(json_args)
        else:
            self.write('JSON Empty!')
            self.json_args = None
```

If I access `http://localhost:9999/discoverjson` I get `'JSON Empty!'`. The problem is if I am trying to send the json I receive `403 (Forbidden)`.

I don't have significant background and perhaps it's not the best approach.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I changed this syntax `self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("/discoverjson")` in `self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "")` and still the access is fobidden.

Client-side console: 
`403 (Forbidden)`

Servers-side console:

```
[W 11:14:38.263 LabApp] 403 POST /discoverjson (172.21.0.1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST
[W 11:14:38.263 LabApp] 403 POST /discoverjson (172.21.0.1) 0.92ms referer=http://localhost:9999/discover/index.html?
```

Comment: `if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("/discoverjson"):`doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be your if statement

```
if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("/discoverjson")
```

Lets break this down a little

```
self.request.headers.get("Content-Type","")
```

This will return `application/json;charset=UTF-8` as this is what you set it to in the Javascript.

So it is never going to start with `/discoverjson`

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Then edit the question properly to show what you actually changed the code to and what problem you are seeing with the new code.

Comment: I actually did that.

Comment: No, the edit you made about the change really isn't clear. I have no idea what you changed and how